# ansible gathering facts fails to retrieve ansible_distribution_release ("module invocation has junk after the json data")

Tags: ansible, ubuntu-20.04

running:

```
ansible -m setup <hostname>
```

(hostname being an ubuntu 20.04 desktop)

returns the warning:

> [WARNING]: Module invocation had junk after the JSON data: AttributeError("module 'platform' has no attribute 'dist'")

and the output does not show any field "ansible_distribution_release".

As expected, tasks using this variable fail:

> 'ansible_distribution_release' is undefined

anything I may be missing ?

edit: the issue occurred with ansible 2.5.1, and was solved by running a newer version of ansible, see accepted answer.

Comment: Do you get the same result when targeting localhost ? Which version of ansible are you using ? If not latest, did you try to upgrade ? Without being exactly identical, this looks like [the following fixed bug](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/37455).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you're running an older version of Ansible.

The use of `platform.dist()` in Ansible was removed in commit [61b1da](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/commit/61b1da), dated Dec. 10 2018. Python itself dropped support for `platform.dist()` in Python 3.8.

With Ansible 2.9.16, running the `setup` module against an Ubuntu 20.04 system yields:

```
$ ansible all -i 192.168.122.212, -u root -m setup | grep ansible_distribution
        "ansible_distribution": "Ubuntu",
        "ansible_distribution_file_parsed": true,
        "ansible_distribution_file_path": "/etc/os-release",
        "ansible_distribution_file_variety": "Debian",
        "ansible_distribution_major_version": "20",
        "ansible_distribution_release": "focal",
        "ansible_distribution_version": "20.04",
```

Comment: indeed, after upgrading (from 2.5.1), things worked again